# Should all methods of a class be at the same level of abstraction?

Tags: object-oriented, architecture

I have a class `APIClient` (Just an example name) which has the methods

```
  def get(url, params={})
    @last_response = conn.get(url, params)
  end

  def post(url, params={})
    @last_response = conn.post(url, params)
  end

  def put(url, params={})
    @last_response = conn.put(url, params)
  end

  def delete(url, params={})
    @last_response = conn.delete(url, params)
  end
```

These methods can be used do do anything on the API but later I have added more methods which implement more specific tasks that I want to do in my application.

Some of these new methods are

`add_category(name)`

`list_products`

`find_category_id(name)`

These methods provide a far higher level interface than the get, post, put and delete methods.

In various places I have seen the comment that statements in functions/methods should all be at the same level of abstraction but I have not seen the same said for methods in a class.

Am I wrong in putting these high level methods in the same class as the low level methods? Would any problems occur due to this and is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in general, a single class should exist at a single level of abstraction. Having multiple levels of abstraction tends to violate the Single Responsibility Principle. And by just tacking on operations, you can build a sort of God Object, breaking down the cohesion of the class. *And* tacking on methods is pretty much the definition of an Open Closed Principle violation.

All that said, there are often very important practical concerns in cases like this. Any sort of operation done via multiple CRUD calls will have concurrency and transactional issues (or requires some awkward, implementation specific hoop-jumping). Caching and cohesive logging can be problematic. Authorization options are limited if you want a user to be able to make some changes but not others. Depending on your implementation, you might be limited in you options about how much data to pull back.

Like any guideline, it’s an idea to help you do the right thing in most cases, not a rule to prevent you from doing things wrong.

Comment: How to know that we are violating single level of abstractions?

Answer (score 4):

The number one problem here is that `APIClient` is a terrible name.  Without good names your code becomes about structure, not intent. Without that it's difficult to tell what the abstraction should be.

A name, a class, an object, a method, should be an abstraction of a clear idea. Not just some level. `HTTP`, `Category`, and `Product` sound like good abstractions. They might not all be at the same level but when you use them you don't have to mix them together.

This might seem like it's side stepping the issue. It is. You should too. Whenever you can. Because this is about more than structural complexity. This is about communicating with humans in a clear vocabulary. But if you can't then yes. It's better not to mix different levels of abstraction together.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that APIClient was just for this question, the actual class is <Appname>Client

Comment: Thanks for the tips on class naming though. I agree with making new classes for Category and Product, makes much more sense than lumping everything in one class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a small program with a very small team you can probably get away with combining them, but I agree with the other posters that this is likely not to serve you will going forward.

The question here is about domain (as in subject matter domain) knowledge. Ideally, you'd have two levels of this API:

1. A CRUD API-- potentially generated via an [EF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx)--, which you can expose to your back-end developer, so he can code business rules into a business rules layer, armed with his knowledge of how the CRUD updates work and what sort of impact there might be on referential integrity, performance, etc. His job will be to expose a business API that masks all the representational concerns and enforces validation and integrity, and performs efficient database operations based on his knowledge of the database structure and indexes available.
2. A business API, which you can give your front-end developer, secure in the knowledge that abusing the business API won't cause corrupted data (assuming the first developer did his job correctly). You don't want to give this guy the CRUD API-- his expertise is in HTML and CSS, not the details of your system. If you gave him access to the CRUD API, he could easily/accidentally bypass business rules and may end up putting garbage into your database.

Separation in this manner also improves your security profile, since you don't expose the all-powerful CRUD API to the web site at all. The business layer can enforce authorization/entitlements/claims and deny calls as needed, possibly based on a session context using context propagation.

Comment: This answer seems to make a lot of implicit assumptions. The structure of the system will - and should be allowed to - depend on organisational structure and constraints.

Comment: Agreed. But its hard to align code structure with organization structure when the code "structure" is just one big heap. That is why I advocate separation.